# Find the limit points of this sequence of polynomials: $p_n(z)=z^2+\frac z{n(n-1)}-\frac1{n(n-1)}$ for different topologies

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, polynomials

A) Let $A=\{a_n|p_n(a_n)=0\}$ be a subset of complex numbers regarded as a sequence in the set of complex numbers with the **metric** topology. Determine all limit points in A.

B) Let $B=\{b_n|p_n(b_n)=0\}$ be a subset of complex numbers regarded as a sequence in the set with the **cofinite** topology. Determine all limit points in B.

My Work:

The sequence will converge as long as $a_n$ is any real number. In which case the sequence converges to ${a_n}^2$. The sequence will also converge for all $a_n$ such that $a_n$ is a sequence that converges to some $\alpha$. In which case, the sequence will converge to $\alpha$

I also claim that these limit points will be valid for either topology because they fall within the bounds of each topology.

I do not think that my answer is correct, as I'm not too confident I know how to find limit points, regardless of how each limit point is dependent on a topology. If someone could provide a valid proof of the problem, I would be greatly appreciative!

Comment: (1) What is $p_n$? (2) If $a_n$ converges, then it converges to a constant, not something that depends on $n$. So no, it does not converge to $a_n^2$. (3) what is the point of saying that if $a_n$ converges to $\alpha$, then $a_n$ converges to $\alpha$? Without knowing what the $p_n$ are, there isn't any way for someone to help you.

Comment: a) $p_n$ is in the title. It is the sequence of quadratic polynomials s.t. $p_n(z)=z^2+\frac{z}{n(n-1)}-\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$. b) as the limit of $n$ goes to infinity, wouldn't the second and third terms converge to zero? c) I'm not really sure, I'm just spitballing

Comment: It doesn't matter (directly) what the 2nd and 3rd terms do as $n \to \infty$, as you are not taking the limit of $p_n$. Instead you are taking the limit of its roots. As such, you have a problem, as each $p_n$ has two roots, so your sequence $a_n$ ($b_n$ is the same sequence, regardless of the topology) is not well-defined.  But my point in (2) is this: Regardless what sequence we are talking about, its limit as $n \to \infty$ **cannot depend on $n$**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$p_n(z) = \frac{n(n-1)z^2 + z - 1}{n(n-1)}$$
so its root are $$\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+4n^2 - 4n}}{2n(n-1)}=\frac{-1 \pm (2n-1)}{2n(n-1)}\\=\frac1n\text{ or }\frac{-1}{n-1}$$($n > 1)$.

So for each $n$, $a_n = b_n$ is either $1/n$ or $-1/(n-1)$, though we don't know which as the information given doesn't completely define the sequence. However, the limits are the same no matter which values are chosen. I trust you can see that $\lim_n a_n = 0$ in the normal topology on $\Bbb C$. For the cofinite topology, note that the sequence does not take any value more than once.